# Calculus over integers for derivative/integral of factorial?

Tags: calculus, factorial, gamma-function, finite-differences, integers

One usually introduces the Gamma function to define a derivative of the factorial. However couldn't one define a derivative over integers like
$$
f'(n) = \frac{f(n+1) - f(n)}{1} ?
$$
Such a discrete alternative to the usual derivative would then allow us to simply compute a derivative of the factorial like
$$
(n!)' = (n+1)! - n! = (n+1)n!-n! = n\ n!
$$
My question is now: Is this the correct way to define a derivative over integer numbers and is the result for the derivative of the factorial correct? And how would one then compute the discrete integral/sum for the factorial?

Comment: Knuth's *Concrete Mathematics* has a lot about this difference operator.

Comment: If you are interested in other ways to calculating the derivative of the factorial, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633014/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-the-derivative-of-x-without-using-gamma-function  Another note is that taking the derivative of Stirling's approximations might be a good approach, if we are to avoid the Gamma function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable. These are called [forward-finite-difference operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). On the same page of the link, you'll find a section on calculus for finite difference operators.

On the other hand, you might be interested in the definition of the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), which generalizes the factorial to non-integers and has a derivative in the classical sense.